# Supremum norm in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, uniform-convergence

Let $I$ be an interval of $\mathbb R$ and $f$ a function defined on $I$, we have  $$\|f\|_\infty=\sup\{|f(x)|;\ x\in I\}$$
This is the version for real functions of one variable of "supremum norm". What is the equivalent for multivariable functions ? Should $I$ be a compact, a closet set, an open set ?

Comment: Are you thinking of *bounded* functions, so that the supremum is defined? Or do you allow $\infty$ as value of the supremum norm? In both cases, the generalization to multivariable functions would be exactly the same definition.

Comment: I actually think that if $f$ is defined on the whole interval then it doesn't need to be continuous to have a sup

Comment: And it is actually wrong by a counter example in the comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The natural generalization is to take a compact set, if you this to be defined for any continuoues functions. In fact, a subset $I$ of $\Bbb R^n$ is compact if and only if every continuous function from $I$ into $\Bbb R$ is bounded.

Comment: Thanks ! But for real functions of one variable, $f$ doesn't need to be continuous right ?

Comment: If $f$ is discontinuous, then $\sup|f|$ may be undefined.

Comment: Do you have any example ? I considered $f(x)= tan(x)$ and $I=[0,10]$ but $f$ is undefined on this interval. So I thought that if $f$ is defined on the whole interval then it doesn't need to be continuous to have $\lVert f \rVert_{\infty}$ that is defined

Comment: Take $I=[0,1]$ and$$f(x)=\begin{cases}0&\text{ if }x=0\\\frac1x&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$

Comment: Ok perfect thanks